# Trouble with django upload_to callable

Tags: python, django

I'm working on uploading a file to a dynamic path based on a model instance. Here is my sample code:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    def _upload_to(instance, filename):
        return '/'.join([instance.username.name, filename])

    username = models.ForeignKey(UserModel) #defined elsewhere
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=_upload_to)
```

And then to test it:

```
>>> t = Test(file="myfile.txt")
>>> t.save()
```

But it doesn't seem to put it in the right path, as I still get:

```
>>> t.file.url
/media/myfile.txt
```

When it should be

```
/media/someusername/myfile.txt
```

What is wrong in this example?

Comment: I'm guessing yes but just to check--have you set a `username` for your instance of `Test`? And does `UserModel` have a `name` attribute?

Comment: This is just an example - my foreign key actually references the django built-in auth User model, and I'm sure I have the field names right.

Comment: So if you do, `print t.username.name`, you'll get `someusername`?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that my callable is not actually being called. I tried adding a print statement, and there was no output. Am I supposed to pass something in when I create a model instance?

Answer (score 1):

Your test isn't actually testing the right thing. The upload_to callable is called when you upload a file, as the name implies, not when you simply save the model. You need to try with an actual upload: perhaps try through the admin site.

When you do, you will almost certainly run into problems because Python will think that the function is an instance method, because you have defined it inside the class. You'll need to take it outside of the class, or decorate it with `@staticmethod`.

Comment: I believe it's perfectly fine where it is because `instance` will be assigned an instance of the model. You can even replace it with `self` if you wanted to.